# Adding Datapoints to a map in C# Visual Studio from a SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, dictionary

I am a beginner in coding. I have coded a data access class that takes the locations from my SQL database, and brings them over to C#.
Next, I am trying to figure out how to display these data points from my database on a google map as markers on a ASPX webpage, and I'm not sure how to do this.
I have around 800 points from a penguin dataset, which are in C#, as I previously stated.

Comment: Have you read https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering ?

Comment: I have looked at that, my problem isnt how to get the markers, but how to use my stored data to add a marker if that makes sense

Comment: I don't quite understand where you're blocked, then. That page gives an example with X number of last long pairs baked into the code. How the latlongs get there is immaterial but I expect your client side script would make a request to the server and receive them from eg your api. As a first step, bake your 800 points into an on page script, then convert it to a "request data from server"?

Comment: Hi, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. There are lots of ways to accomplish what you are asking, so at least providing what you have tried so far gives other users more context when answering your question.

Comment: Basically, I have been able to make a div class with all of the markers inside of it in my aspx page. What I am trying to accomplish is getting these markers onto a google map on my page. Each marker has latitude and longitude, so I need a code I can run these through to display them. Every code I have seen includes values that are manually put into the program, including the one that was provided by both of you. What I am inquiring about is something that will allow me to transfer the values from a div class onto the map, without manually inputting 700 of my datasets coordinates myself.